# chromium build hangs and crashes due to insufficient RAM amount

Tags: build, chromium

I'm trying to build chromium on my laptop (i7-1260P, 16Gb RAM) under Ubuntu.
What I do:

```
gn gen out/Default
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

At some point build process hangs and I see a significant raise of memory consumption in the System monitor (it rases from the 5Gb to 16Gb in 10-15 seconds). Also I see almost an 100% load of every of my processors. After it build process crashes with error:

```
[31140/52638] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/browser_plugin_guest.o
FAILED: obj/content/browser/browser/browser_plugin_guest.o 
ccache ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -MMD -MF obj/content/browser/browser/browser_plugin_guest.o.d -DDCHECK_ALWAYS_ON=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D_GNU_SOURCE -
<<<<<<<<<<<<A LOT OF ROWS WITH BUILD VARIABLES, LINKING ETC>>>>>>>>>>>>>
_plugin_guest.cc -o obj/content/browser/browser/browser_plugin_guest.o
[31151/52638] CXX obj/content/browser/browser/browser_interface_binders.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The build process creates many `clang++` processes (about 12), each of which consumes about 200 MB of memory (before the memory consumption starts to grow uncontrollably).
I tried to find some build argument which could reduce number of parallel processes but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

i7-1260P, 16Gb RAM - this is too weak hardware for linking the whole Chromium. You should use the component build. Add the following line into your `args.gn`

```
is_component_build = true
```

The other useful tunings: [Linker Crashes](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#linker-crashes).

Comment: 7-1260P, 16Gb RAM is weak, really?)) Btw, google thinks otherwise - https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#System-requirements. I tried is_component_build - doesn't work. I solved it via ninja flag "-j<number of processes>"

Comment: `is_component_build` is only suitable for debug versions. I wouldn't use it for release builds as it will generate lots of shared libraries

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved it via `ninja` flag `v` which set number of parallel processes.
For example I reduced processes amount to 8 (from 16) and it works:

```
autoninja -C out/Default chrome -j8
```